# How to update blank rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with data (stored as `INTEGER`) with some `NULL` values. I want to set all NULL values to 0.

I tried `UPDATE table
    SET data = 0 WHERE (data = '') IS NOT FALSE;`

Apparently this only works for strings. Any ideas where the data is type `integer` or `numeric`?

Comment: Do you want to delete (=remove) them, or set them to zero?

Comment: Do you mean `NULL` values?

Comment: I have some values are NULL  and some are just blank.

Comment: @joop I have 2 tables. One I want to delete the blanks and the other I want to set them to 0.

Comment: integers cannot be *blank*. Either they are NULL or they have a value.

Comment: Something is wrong when you have blank rows, probably learn some database design.

Comment: @joop You were correct. The values were NULL. The following worked:
'UPDATE table
 SET data = 0 WHERE data IS NULL;'
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question so other people can understand it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joop pointed out, integer values are `NULL` not blank. 
The following worked to delete all `NULL` rows.

```
UPDATE table 
SET data = 0 WHERE data IS NULL;
```